# bash - using a command line argument (hostname) to run an external command

Tags: bash, centos, arguments, command, line

First time post, please forgive any missing information.

I have a script that is supposed to work with icinga. I need icinga to log into my Linux box and run a command like "script ". The script will then run a command to that hostname like sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status then report back "running or unused" and an exit status of 0 or 2.
I'm wondering how I could add another command and have it one or the other run depending on what hostname it's given. Half of them need apache2 to be running and the other half need to have a process called dss to be running. I'd rather not have two separate scripts. Here is the working script and sorry it's sloppy but I haven't done any clean up and I'm not real good at bash yet.

so the user would run the script ./chkdss2  or

```
#!/bin/bash
ec=0
ec1=2
var3=run
var4=unused

for host in "$@"
do
  var1=`ssh $host sudo /etc/init.d/dss status|awk '{print $6}'`
  var2="$( echo $var1 | cut -c 3-5 )"
if [[ "$var2" == "$var3" ]]; then
    echo "$host is running"
    echo $ec
  else
    echo "$host is not running"
    echo $ec1
fi
done
```

Comment: Do you have a list of hostnames and the services that need to be checked on them (e.g. format `hostname1 dss ... hostname9 apache2 ...`)?  Alternatively, to you want the program to check each host to find out what service is running before doing the appropriate status check?  If my question isn't clear, maybe try providing more information (e.g. pseudocode) about what *exactly* you want to do.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, first post and all. 
Server 1 is an automation server that only sends commands. We'll program it to send a command to my server that will invoke my script. 
ex: ssh 10.x.x.x script.sh hostname1
my script them takes that hostname and make a call to another server that only it can reach:
ex ssh $host sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status. 
I have to manipulate the text I get back to isolate "running"
If my script matches "running" then it needs to exit with an exit status 0 else 2.

Comment: This much I've pretty much figured out but some of the server I make calls to don't use apache2, they use a command called dss.
ex: ssh $host sudo /etc/init.d/dss status.
What I need to do is be able to run one command or the other depending on what the hostname is. For this example lets call the ones that use apache: ap1 ap2 ap3 and the ones that use the dss command: dss1 dss2 dss3.

Comment: @nic3500 Thank you for that advice. I've been researching case for the last hour and I think that's going to be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a  couple ways to test if a particular hostname is for apache or dss.  You only need to have a list of hostnames for each case, and check if the received hostnames are included in said lists.

**Method 1**: using arrays

```
#!/bin/bash

# Method 1, using array lists of hosts
apachehosts=('ap1' 'ap2' 'ap3')
dsshosts=('dss1' 'dss2' 'dss3')

for host in "$@"
do
    if printf '%s\n' "${apachehosts[@]}" | grep -Fxq "$host"
    then
        echo "$host: APACHE HOST"
    elif printf '%s\n' "${dsshosts[@]}" | grep -Fxq "$host"
    then
        echo "$host: DSS HOST"
    else
        echo "ERROR, $host: unknown host"
    fi
done
```

To modify the lists of hosts, simply add or remove values in the declaration of arrays `apachehosts` and `dsshosts`.

---

**Method 2**: using `case`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Method 2, using case
for host in "$@"
do
    case "$host" in
        'ap1'|'ap2'|'ap3')
            echo "CASE, $host: APACHE HOST"
            ;;
        'dss1'|'dss2'|'dss3')
            echo "CASE, $host: DSS HOST"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "ERROR CASE, $host: unknown host"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Here, you edit the patterns in each case.

---

**Method 3:** using `if`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Method 3, using if
for host in "$@"
do
    if [[ "$host" == 'ap1' || "$host" == 'ap2' || "$host" == 'ap3' ]]
    then
        echo "IF, $host: APACHE HOST"
    elif [[ "$host" == 'dss1' || "$host" == 'dss2' || "$host" == 'dss3' ]]
    then
        echo "IF, $host: DSS HOST"
    else
        echo "IF, $host: unknown host"
    fi
done
```

Here you modify the `if` conditions.  I prefer the other methods, since this one is more complicated to edit, it is not as clear, especially if your list of hosts is long.

---

**Method 4**: condition on the hostnames

If you are lucky, there is some pattern to your hostnames.  Ex. all apache servers start with letters `ap`, all your dss servers include `dss` in the name, ...

You can then simply use 2 if statements to decide which is which.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Method 4, patterns
for host in "$@"
do
    if [[ $(echo "$host" | grep -c -e "^ap") -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo "PATTERNS, $host: APACHE HOST"
    elif [[ $(echo "$host" | grep -c -e "dss") -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo "PATTERNS, $host: DSS host"
    else
        echo "PATTERNS, $host: unknown host"
    fi
done
```

**Note**: hostname `apdss1` would come out as an Apache server here.  Previous methods would respond "unknown host".  You patterns must be strict enough to avoid mismatches.

Comment: Sure, please accept the answer (the checkmark on the left of the answer) if it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task to get few report items using single `ssh` request.

I had to retrieve in singel `ssh` command:

1. Full hostname (FQDN)
2. Linux version
3. IP address of its Docker host if exist, or "none"

I got my script to work in 3 stage.

#### 1. Get multiple lines of information from remote host

```
ssh -q dudi-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-MT  <<< '
date +%F:%T   # line 1: time stamp
hostname -f     # line 2: hostname 
awk  "/DESCR/{print \$3}" /etc/lsb-release # line 3 : host linux distribution version
ip a | awk "/inet / && !/127.0.0.1/{sub(\"/.*\",\"\",\$2);printf(\"%s \", \$2)}"      # line 4: list IP address to the host
'
```

##### Results:

```
2022-03-05:22:22:21
dudi-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-MT
20
192.168.2.111 192.168.122.1 172.17.0.1
```

#### 2. Process multiple lines of information from remote host

Read lines of information from remote host, into an array `sshResultsArr`.

```
readarray -t sshResultsArr < <(ssh -q dudi-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-MT  <<< '
date +%F:%T   # line 1: time stamp
hostname -f     # line 2: hostname 
awk  "/DESCR/{print \$3}" /etc/lsb-release # line 3 : host linux distribution version
ip a | awk "/inet / && !/127.0.0.1/{sub(\"/.*\",\"\",\$2);printf(\"%s \", \$2)}"      # line 4: list IP address to the host
')
hostname=${sshResultsArr[1]}
osVersion=${sshResultsArr[2]}
hasDockerIp=$(grep -Eo "172(.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}" <<< "${sshResultsArr[3]}") # find IP starting with 172
hasDockerIp=${hasDockerIp:="none"} # if not found IP set to "NONE"

printf "%s \t OS version: %s \t has Docker IP: %s\n" "$hostname" "$osVersion" "$hasDockerIp"
```

##### Result:

```
dudi-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-MT     OS version: 20          has Docker IP: 172.17.0.1
```

#### 3. Process each remote host in a loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for host in "$@"; do
  readarray -t sshResultsArr < <(ssh -q $host  <<< '
  date +%F:%T   # line 1: time stamp
  hostname -f     # line 2: hostname 
  awk  "/DESCR/{print \$3}" /etc/lsb-release # line 3 : host linux distribution version
  ip a | awk "/inet / && !/127.0.0.1/{sub(\"/.*\",\"\",\$2);printf(\"%s \", \$2)}"      # line 4: list IP address to the host
  ')
  hostname=${sshResultsArr[1]}
  osVersion=${sshResultsArr[2]}
  hasDockerIp=$(grep -Eo "172(.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}" <<< "${sshResultsArr[3]}") # find IP starting with 172
  hasDockerIp=${hasDockerIp:="none"} # if not found IP set to "NONE"

  printf "%s \t OS version: %s \t has Docker IP: %s\n" "$hostname" "$osVersion" "$hasDockerIp"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take a little bit from the answers I received and put together something that works well. Thank you all for your answers.

```
for host in "$@"
do
    case "$host" in
       ('vho1uc1-primary'|'vho1uc2-backup'|'vho2uc1-primary'|'vho2uc2-backup'|'vho3uc1-primary'|'vho3uc2-backup'|'vho10uc1-primary')
          var1=`ssh "$host" sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status|awk '{print $4}'`
          var2="$( echo $var1 | cut -c 3-5 )"
            if [[ "$var2" == "$var3" ]]; then
          echo "Apache2 on $host is running"
          echo "0"
            else
          echo "Apache2 on $host is not running"
          echo "2"
          fi
          ;;
       *)
    esac
done
```